# how to install a pre-downloading package by using brew command

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

When running this command "brew install pypy" on Mac OS X 10.9.2, I got the following error:

> curl: (7) Failed connect to cdn.bitbucket.org:80; Operation timed out
>
> Error: Failed to download resource "pypy"
>
> Download failed: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy-2.2.1-osx64.tar.bz2

and then I downloaded pypy-2.2.1-osx64.tar.bz2 from the http://pypy.org/download.html, put this package to /Library/Caches/Homebrew, and then run "brew install", but failed to install that package.

Would anyone please help me to install this package?

Answer (score 4):

As (now) explained in Homebrew documentation at https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N%27-Tricks use

```
brew --cache -s curl
```

(or whatever package name you are trying to pre-download), and it will tell you exactly where it expects to find the file and what it expects it to be called.  Put the downloaded file there, then run the brew install command for it and it should find it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that homebrew is out-of-date and trying to fetch and old version of pypy.  Try running the following:

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew doctor
```